# Is $\frac{O(2,1)}{O(1,1)}$ connected?

Tags: lie-groups, connectedness, quotient-spaces

The Anti-de Sitter space is $AdS_n=\frac{O(2,n-1)}{O(1,n-1)}$, as a homogeneous symmetric space.

Is the space connected or not, especially for $n=2$?

Is there a general method to judge that?